# Pagination and Controller setup

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, pagination, active-record

Below is some code that I've been working to simplify, however I feel there is more that can be done. Please note that I did clean up the `articles.search` method.

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    @@articles_per_page = 6
     def index
        @paged_articles = articles.search(:user_id=> @@user_id, :page=>'1', :per_page=>@@articles_per_page)
        @tags = get_tags
        @next_page_url = url_for(:controller =>:home, :action => :page, :page_id=>  2)
        @page_title = "Recent articles"
     end

    def tags
      @paged_articles = articles.search(:page=>'1',:tags=>params[:tag_name], :per_page=>@@articles_per_page)
       @tags = get_tags
       @next_page_url = url_for(:controller =>:home, :action => :page, :tag_name => params[:tag_name], :page_id=>  2)
       @page_title = "Search articles by tags"
       render :index
     end

    def about
       @page_title = "About"
    end    

   private
    def get_tags
         articles.getTags 'param1', 'param2'
    end
   end
```

I simplified it this way

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  @@articles_per_page = 6
  @@first_page_articles_options = {:page=>'1', :per_page=>@@articles_per_page}
  @@second_page_url_options = {:controller =>:home, :action => :page, :page_id=>  2}


  def index
    @paged_articles = articles.search(@@first_page_articles_options)
    @tags = get_tags
    @next_page_url = url_for(@@second_page_url_options)
    @page_title = "Recent articles"
  end

  def tags
    @@first_page_articles_options[:tags]  = params[:tag_name]
    @paged_articles = articles.search(@@first_page_articles_options)
    @tags = get_tags

    @@second_page_url_options[:tag_name]  = params[:tag_name]
    @next_page_url = url_for(@@second_page_url_options)
    @page_title = "Search articles by tags"
    render :index
  end
   def about
      @page_title = "About"
  end

  private
  def get_tags
         articles.getTags 'param1', 'param2'
  end
end
```

So what do you think? Is there any way to make it more better and cleaner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move urls and titles to helpers and articles search to separate method

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  # this methods can be used in view template
  helper_method :next_page_url, :page_title

  @@articles_per_page = 6
  @@first_page_articles_options = {:page=>'1', :per_page=>@@articles_per_page}
  @@second_page_url_options = {:controller =>:home, :action => :page, :page_id=>  2}


  def index
    @paged_articles = articles.search(@@first_page_articles_options)
    @tags = get_tags
  end

  def tags
    @paged_articles = load_articles
    @tags = get_tags

    render :index
  end
   def about
      @page_title = "About"
  end

  private

    def load_articles
      ...
    end 

  ...

  # helpers

  def next_page_url
    if filter_by_tags?
      url_for(@@second_page_url_options)  
    else
      @@second_page_url_options[:tag_name] = params[:tag_name]
      url_for(@@second_page_url_options)
    end    
  end

  def page_title
    if filter_by_tags?
      "Recent articles" 
    else
      "Search articles by tags"
    end  
  end

  def filter_by_tags?
    params[:tag_name].present?
  end
end
```

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: update my answer

Comment: There is no implementation of helper method yet.

Comment: next_page_url and page_title declared as helper methods and available in views, see http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method

Comment: You should use constants where you use class variables here.